# Limit of spotify requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, spotify

I am developing a site which uses the Spotify Web API.

On the support page I haven't seen any information about how many requests you can send to the API before it blocks it. My question:

- is there a certain limit of requests?

Comment: Their [Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#rate-limiting) indicates that request limits do apply, but doesn't indicate at what amount. I'm sure they limit the number of requests to prevent flooding, but you should contact their support to get the actual number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mod comment:

> The rate limit for signed requests varies according to the endpoint, current load, origin, etc., however it should always be better than the rate limit for unsigned requests and it should always be sufficient for normal use. If you are hitting rate limits on a regular basis, consider using conditional requests, making use of caching mechanisms, adjusting paging limits, etc.

So they do not specify the limit, they calculate it dynamically, so no way to control the request limit for the developer.