# Spotify API Policy change?

Tags: spotify

I'm using a process similar to this one: http://static.echonest.com/playlistminer/index.html and, since last week, it seems that it doesn't work anymore due to a large amount of "API rate limit exceeded". Is there any policy change for the API, or is it an issue ?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531724/limit-of-spotify-requests)  or the [Spotify documentation on rate limits](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#rate-limiting)?

Comment: Actually, each requests I send are authenticated by token, limits are set on the highest possible limit to prevent a large amount of requests, also, I can't use the Get Several Tracks API, because I'm using the Get Playlist's Tracks. 10 parallel requests always worked since last week, I also tried with 2 parallel requests, and it didn't worked.