# R - Spotify API - Delay

Tags: r, spotify

I'm using the below to extract the genres of a list of artists. While the list has approx. 400 artist ID's in there the result only keeps showing me a 100 artists. I'm assuming there is a limit to the API. Any recommendations on how to add a delay / or a different approach to extract this info for more than a 100 artists?

```
library(Rspotify)

keys <- spotifyOAuth("*****","*******","***********")

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

# Create a vector of owners id 

artist_id <- c(artist$artistId)

artist_id

################

# Create empty list

datalist = list()

# Tell loop to iterate over all entries p in artist_id

for(p in artist_id) {
pl <- getArtistinfo(p ,token=keys) %>%  
mutate(artist_id = p)  
datalist[[p]] <- pl   
}

artiestfile <- do.call(rbind, datalist)

artiestfile
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of spotify requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531724/limit-of-spotify-requests)

Comment: I've had a similar thing, maybe `testit <- function(x)
{
    p1 <- proc.time()
    Sys.sleep(x)
    proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}
testit(3.7)`